# Reading from Analog Mic and Transmitting over BLE (Nano 33 BLE)

Tags: adc, ble, analog-sampling, arduino-nano-ble

I'm trying to read from an analog mic with a sampling frequency of 10 kHz and transmitting the data over BLE on Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense Rev 2. The MCU reaches that sampling rate with no problem but once I activate BLE it starts having a delay too big to keep up with the 10kHz

Is it possible doing something like this on Arduino, or will I have to try with a different chip?